# Switching positions of boxes?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm beginning with Unity and want to start of with some concepts to work on. Basically what I want to do is: if I click on the right side of the screen, switch the position of the blue and yellow boxes, and if I subsequently click the right side of the screen switch the yellow box with the red box. I have already set up the canvas for the left and right side of the screen. What would I need to do this?

[EDIT]: The error that I'm having can be seen in the picture. I'm not sure if I should be using a different approach to solve this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

[Switching positions of boxes error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoOa0.png)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Add this to a button and set object references:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class SwapObjectPositions : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform transformA;
public Transform transformB;

    void Start () {
        GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(SwapPositions);
    }

    public void SwapPositions()
    {
        if (transformA==null || transformB==null) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Set object references in the inspector please"); 
            return;
        }
        Vector3 posA=transformA.position;
        transformA.position=transformB.position;
        transformB.position=posA;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I'm having an issue with the code used. In the image I attached there is an error in after the first left and right click. The error is that the red and yellow should've switched (2nd picture in diagram), but instead the switch code is comparing the two colors that I've attached to TransformA and TransformB (the blue and red colored boxed). What changed would I have to make to the code to fix this? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have 3 boxes that switch places, not just two. After the first swap the order change. You must make something like that :

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class SwapObjectPositions : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform[] boxTransform;
public Button LeftButton;
public Button RightButton;

void Start()
{
    if (LeftButton == null || RightButton == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button reference missing");
    }
    LeftButton.onClick.AddListener(LeftSwap);
    RightButton.onClick.AddListener(RightSwap);
    if (boxTransform.Length != 3 || boxTransform[0] == null || boxTransform[1] == null || boxTransform[2] == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Boxes reference missing");
    }
}

public void LeftSwap()
{
    // Swap Positions
    Vector3 tempPosition = boxTransform[0].position;
    boxTransform[0].position = boxTransform[1].position;
    boxTransform[1].position = tempPosition;
    // Swap Transform
    Transform tempTransform = boxTransform[0];
    boxTransform[0] = boxTransform[1];
    boxTransform[1] = tempTransform;
}

public void RightSwap()
{
    // Swap Positions
    Vector3 tempPosition = boxTransform[1].position;
    boxTransform[1].position = boxTransform[2].position;
    boxTransform[2].position = tempPosition;
    // Swap Transform
    Transform tempTransform = boxTransform[1];
    boxTransform[1] = boxTransform[2];
    boxTransform[2] = tempTransform;
}
}
```

Comment: Hi Adrien! Thanks for your help! I've implemented the code and it works perfectly. I have a question about the Swap Position and the Swap Transform code. Specifically, what is it the difference between the two?

Comment: The transform is in this code a reference to the box. So if you swap the position of 2 box, swap the position of their reference in the array. With this, the array will represent exactly what you see on your screen.
But swaping their reference will not change their position, so you also need to change the position of each box (transform.position)